# How to read stdin in a Haskell program with command-line arguments?

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments, stdin

I know I can use `interact :: (String -> String) -> IO ()` to conveniently read from stdin and write to stdout in a simple Haskell program (see http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output).

Now I would like to add command-line arguments to make my simple program "configurable".

Is there a way to do this and still use `interact` (so as to obtain a configurable program with minimum effort)?

Comment: I've never used `interact` before. Why is it a requirement?

Comment: Using `interact` is not a requirement, it's just what I happened to have learned so far, and being able to extend my program with minimal modifications (in this case, still using `interact`) would be convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most programs, `interact` is quickly replaced with the alternative of using `getContents` and `putStr`. This is because `interact` is very limiting in that you can only call a single function, and that single function must consume all of the input. As the complexity of the program rises, you will eventually want to break up the program into smaller functions that handle a piece of the input at a time, and the `do` notation makes sequencing these functions much easier.

So to mimic `interact` but also use command-line arguments, you might initially do this:

```
import System.Environment

doStuff :: [String] -> String -> String
doStuff args input = undefined -- your code here

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    contents <- getContents
    putStr (doStuff args contents)
```

Which, by the way, is the same as:

```
main = doStuff <$> getArgs <*> getContents >>= putStr
```

But later you may wish to add things like prompts, parsers, or file I/O:

```
import System.Environment

data Arg = Taco | Boring

parseArg :: String -> Arg
parseArg arg = if arg == "taco" then Taco else Boring

doStuff :: Arg -> String -> String
doStuff Taco   input = "Yum, tacos! " ++ input
doStuff Boring input = "Meh, " ++ input

main :: IO ()
main = do
    [arg] <- map parseArg <$> getArgs
    putStr "Enter the file name: "
    fileName <- getLine
    fileContents <- readFile fileName
    writeFile ("output-" ++ fileName) (doStuff arg fileContents)
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by "sequencing" IO computations with `do` and use `getArgs` before using `interact`:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    interact (<whatever using args>)
```